# concatenation of the variable in the middle of the imported string in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I create a special js file in which I will map all my api endpoints that I will import into my redux-saga:

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'https://localhost:3000/api';
export const USERS = '/Users';

export default {
  users: {
    example: `${API_BASE_URL}${USERS}/example`,
    checkEmail: `${API_BASE_URL}${USERS}${HERE_I_NEED_MY_VARIABLE}/checkEmail`,
  },
};
```

but my endpoint looks like this:

```
import { api } from 'utils';

export function* checkEmail({ value }) {
  const requestURL = `https://localhost:3000/api/Users/${value}/checkEmail`;
  // I would like to do this: (pseudocode) const requestURL = `${api.users.checkEmail} + ${value}`
  ...
};
```

How can I do it to make it look nice and professional? Does the latest js allow you to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store your urls into functions, this way you could pass some parameters to fill the gaps.

```
export const API_BASE_URL = 'https://localhost:3000/api';
export const USERS = '/Users';

export default {
  users: {
    example: () => `${API_BASE_URL}${USERS}/example`,
    checkEmail: (variable) => `${API_BASE_URL}${USERS}/${variable}/checkEmail`,
  },
};
```

then you call it like any other functions.

```
import { api } from 'utils';

export function* checkEmail({ value }) {
  const requestURL = `${api.users.checkEmail(value)}`
  ...
};
```

I've also replace your string concatenation in your string template because i'm not sure that's what you wanted.